# ViewPager2 error androidx....RecycleView.Adapter) in ViewPager2 can not be applied

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

I converted my old viewPager adapter to the new viewPager2 adapter. 
I get error when i setAdapter to viewPager2.

> setAdapter(androidx.viewpager.widget.RecycleView.Adapter) in
>   ViewPager2 can not be applied to ViewPagerAdapter

[image]

my **ViewPagerAdapter**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    /**
     * Contains all the fragments.
     */
    private List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Creates a new PagerAdapter instance.
     *
     * @param fragmentManager The FragmentManager.
     */
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    /**
     * Adds the fragment to the list, also adds the fragment's tab title.
     *
     * @param fragment New instance of the Fragment to be associated with this tab.
     */
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        fragments.add(fragment);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes importing that

Comment: `import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;`?

Comment: kindly show code snippet please.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong type of adapter need to change to `FragmentStateAdapter` https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/adapter/FragmentStateAdapter

See https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)

> If you're planning to use Fragments as pages, implement FragmentStateAdapter

Comment: Thanks @Andrew but i won't be able to use BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT

Comment: In my previous question you suggested me to use ViewPager2 adapter, i converted but now having this issue.

Comment: Viewpager2 only does the same behaviour as `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT `, viewpager with `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT ` set or viewpager2 both only resume the current Fragment ( see https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#1.0.0-alpha06 when they implemented that in viewpager2 ) hence the reason for the option of viewpager2