# how to solve this problem in set adapter i'm trying to setadapter for creating tablayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, android-debug, android-developer-api

'setAdapter(androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter)' in 'androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager' cannot be applied to '(com.example.tablayout.viewpager)'

```
package com.example.tablayout;

import android.os.Bundle;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TabLayout tab=findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        ViewPager viewPager=findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewpager viewp=new viewpager(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewp);

    }
```

Comment: You have a problem in your adapter, Chek out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60835863/viewpager2-error-androidx-recycleview-adapter-in-viewpager2-can-not-be-appli

Comment: i cant understand with above example please help me with my code

Comment: Show us your vieepager adapter

Comment: viewp in second last line is the adapter

Comment: Man your adapter class

Comment: package com.example.tablayout;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter;
public class viewpager extends FragmentStateAdapter { public viewpager(@NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity) {
        super(fragmentActivity); }
NonNull
    Override public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        if(position==0) return new Fragment1();
        else if(position==1)  return new Fragment2();
        else return new Fragment3();}
}

Comment: Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}

Comment: @Moataz here is my adapter class

Comment: watch this video bro https://youtu.be/ziJ6-AT3ymg